# Custom Segment Controlled UITableView

Tags: swift, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol, nib

I'm trying to create a UISegmentedControl, in which, when a segment is selected, it changes the table view and the cells change accordingly. But unfortunately an empty table appears, and when you select the segment again, the application crashes.
Please help me find and fix the bugs.

class PriceViewController: UIViewController {

```
var priceDictionary: [String : String] = [
    "мини-тату": "2000-4000р",
    "перманент бровей" : "4500р",
    "коррекция" : "50% от тату",
    "коррекция пм бровей" : "2500"
]

var stockDictionary: [String : String] = [
    "Скидка имениннику 20%":"Скидка действительна 3 дня до дня рождения и 3 дня после, при предъявлении оригинала документа, удостоверяющего личность. Скидка не распространяется на другие акции.",
    "Две и более мини-тату со скидкой 30%": "Скидка предоставляется при оформлении записи на 2 и более мини-тату за один сейчас.",
    "Скидка для подружек": "Приведи подругу и получу скидку на следующую татуировку/перманент/коррекцию 15%."
]

@IBOutlet var sideMenuBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedController: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    self.sideMenuBtn.target = revealViewController()
    self.sideMenuBtn.action = #selector(self.revealViewController()?.revealSideMenu)
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    switch segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: PriceCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: PriceCell.identifier)
        tableView.reloadData()
    case 1 :
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: StockCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: StockCell.identifier)
        tableView.reloadData()
    default:
        break
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.revealViewController()?.gestureEnabled = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.revealViewController()?.gestureEnabled = true
}

func loadCellPrice(indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PriceCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! PriceCell
    cell.nameOfServiceLabel?.text = Array(priceDictionary.keys)[indexPath.row]
    cell.priceLabel?.text = Array(priceDictionary.values)[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func loadCellStock(indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StockCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! StockCell
    cell.nameStock?.text = Array(stockDictionary.keys)[indexPath.row]
    cell.descriptionStock?.text = Array(stockDictionary.values)[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

}

extension PriceViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        return priceDictionary.count
    case 1 :
        return stockDictionary.count
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        return loadCellPrice(indexPath: indexPath)
    case 1 :
        return loadCellStock(indexPath: indexPath)
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have not implemented the `valueChanged` method for your code to work when the segment controller is toggled.

Please add this code to your `viewController` and connect the `@IBAction` from the storyboard. It should work:

```
@IBAction func segmentValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I did as you said, but it still does not work, the table is empty and when switching back to the first segment, the application crashes.

Comment: Then I think you are going wrong somewhere else. Is it possible for you to share your code in a sample project and reproduce the same steps? Then I can take a look and help.

Comment: Additionally please confirm you have set the `delegate` and `datasource` for the `tableview` as well as make sure you do not have any disconnected `@IBOutlets` or `@IBActions`.
Not setting the delegate and datasource can be a reason for seeing blank tableviews.
And having a disconnected IBOutlet or IBAction can lead to a crash. 
Please share the crash message also if possible to give some perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You should register both tableView cells before using it.

Along with the @Cedan answer, change the below implementation in your viewDidLoad method

```
 switch segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex {
case 0:
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: PriceCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: PriceCell.identifier)
    tableView.reloadData()
case 1 :
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: StockCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: StockCell.identifier)
    tableView.reloadData()
default:
    break
}
```

To

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: PriceCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: PriceCell.identifier)
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: StockCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: StockCell.identifier)
```